hope to use a PC to clone an external SSD to an internal file, then back to another external SSD
I can run a copy utility on a Windows 11 PC or a Linux Fedora 40 laptop.
I have a Windows (10 or 11) M.2 SSD 100GB from another laptop and want to copy it to a new 1T M.2 SSD.  The old SSD works fine and we simply need more capacity.
Is there any free software that allows me to do this with a single USB SSD adapter, first sucking the contents of the first SSD via USB into local disk, then switching SSD's, and blowing it back out to the second SSD via the same cable?
There are a lot of instructions for Clonezilla, EaseUS, etc., that seem to assume you have the constraint of only having one computer, so add the complexity of making some special boot media for copy software, then boot with that minimal environment, copy the internal SSD to an external SSD (actually not even clear it can be external--maybe it has to be in a second internal slot, which I don't have??).  But since I have more computers, surely I could just do this without any special boot, and without needing two adapter cables?

Quite a few backup utilities, including clonezilla will do disk to disk. Do you actually need/want the intermediary local disk?

@JourneymanGeek I don't have an USB M.2 adapter and will have to buy one, at least, for this project.  I'd rather copy the small external SSD to internal file, then internal file to the big external SSD, than make a special boot media and do the whole job on the patient laptop.  And also don't want to buy two adapters to copy old external directly to new external.  Besides the work of making a boot media, the keyboard is Japanese (very different than what I use) and the little screen is very hard to read with my bad eyes.  I'd prefer doing the whole job on my big desktop if possible.

@JourneymanGeek just to be clear I don't have a whole blank internal disk or partition to use as a temporary store.  I'm hoping there's a utility that can just write to and read from a plain old file ON the local disk.

In which case you're 'essentially' just imaging the disk, and restoring it. Other than needing to reboot the PC to swap the M.2 in the PC that's imaging it and restoring it, I think most backup software would do that. Wouldn't need a whole partition, just enough free space

@JourneymanGeek just to be clear, by "imaging" you mean, turning the old SSD content into a disk file, right?  Then I'd put that disk file on the new SSD?  Why would I need to reboot the PC to do this?  Note that this SSD has nothing to do with the PC I'm using to copy.  I'm not opening the copying PC.  I'm not copying the copying PC's SSD.  Both the old and new SSD are external to the copying PC and would be connected only to a USB-->M.2 cable.

Oh, then you don't need to. I was assuming an internal SSD slot

@JourneymanGeek so can clonezilla 1) run as a normal app, and 2) copy a USB-mounted M.2 SSD to and from an image file?  If not, do you know a utility that can?


Clonezilla should run independently, as live session, booting from any USB stick, even a very small one. NOT from a running OS. 2) Yes, obviously, that's one of the most typical functions of any similar tool. Or, again, drive to drive if possible. All are very easy to follow options in Clonezilla's beginner mode.


@ChanganAuto Why would a tool to copy a disk require a special boot, if you're not copying a disk in the running computer?  (Of course a running OS is constantly updating its disk so I see why that wouldn't work.)  I don't want a special boot.  I just want a copy utility that I can download, run, create a file from a USB-attached M.2 SSD, then write that file onto a second USB-attached M.2 SSD.  I don't see why I need to reboot for this.  Do you know of such a utility?  I understand why it needs that complexity if you only have 1 PC.  But I have several.

@ChanganAuto Or, again, drive to drive if possible -- why?  I'd need to buy two cables to do that.  Why would that be any easier than just copying drive1 to an image file, then attaching drive2, and copying the image file to that disk?

I missed the part about linux - clonezilla uses partclone under the hood- I've never used it before but it will back up a partition to an image, and back out. Might need some experimentation to do all the partitions on a disk to an image , and potentially resizing

@JourneymanGeek thanks.  Looking at the partclone site it's not clear to me if there's a way to use it directly or whether it really needs to be used by a higher-level tool.  So again, can I simply run clonezilla on a running Linux box, without making boot media etc., to clone an external USB-M.2 SSD adapter, and make an internal file, then write that back out to a differend SSD via the same cable (after swapping drives)?  If clonezilla can run on a command prompt, what download do I start with?  If it doesn't, what other utility could I use?

partclone is a standalone linux install + partclone (and friends) and some scripts. I'm trying to figure out how best to approach the problem (I need to mess with some windows installs anyway) and probably can try to compose an answer when I've figured out how. I have some ideas but I need to line up a few things first

I don't know why this question is getting downvotes.  I bet practically everyone 1) has to copy a disk at some point and 2) has multiple computers so they can use a computer other than the host of the sick disk to do the copy and 3) has limited time to waste making boot media into unfamiliar environments.

Assuming its linux - I believe a simple dd (or gnu ddrescue - I prefer the syntax), to an image, restoring the image, then resizing the image would be one's best bet. While I don't have a RH box to hand - least on ubuntu there's two applications called ddrescue, and you want the gnu/gddrescue version. I will also use partclone to resize. In theory any good windows backup software will do this, but I don't have a free one I trust
I'd use lsblk to identify the name of the device
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    1  58.6G  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    1  58.6G  0 part
└─sda2        8:2    1     1M  0 part
sdb           8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sdb1        8:17   0 931.4G  0 part
nvme1n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─nvme1n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/grub
│                                     /boot/efi
├─nvme1n1p3 259:2    0     2G  0 part
└─nvme1n1p4 259:3    0   929G  0 part
nvme0n1     259:4    0 238.5G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:5    0    16M  0 part
└─nvme0n1p2 259:6    0 238.5G  0 part

I'd say that in this case, our backup software is agnostic to the format and interface used, and since we're doing a 'simple' backup and restore there's not much to do
In this case I'm backing up nvme0n1
geek@zephyr:~$ sudo ddrescue /dev/nvme0n1 winbackup.img
[sudo] password for geek:
GNU ddrescue 1.27
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
     ipos:   16521 MB, non-trimmed:        0 B,  current rate:   1375 MB/s
     opos:   16521 MB, non-scraped:        0 B,  average rate:   1270 MB/s
non-tried:  239539 MB,  bad-sector:        0 B,    error rate:       0 B/s
  rescued:   16521 MB,   bad areas:        0,        run time:         13s
pct rescued:    6.45%, read errors:        0,  remaining time:          3m
                              time since last successful read:          0s
Copying non-tried blocks... Pass 1 (forwards)

Give it time to do its thing. Its a full disk image so it'll take into account things like the bootloader and multiple partitions on a windows install.
Now I'm going to try restoring this to another, bigger drive
 sudo ddrescue --force winbackup.img /dev/sdb
In your case, you'd want to remove your source drive, swap out the m.2 for the destination drive, and check the device name again. Since I already had mine plugged in, we're probably good. Since the drive is an existing device, you need to overwrite it, and naturally this is destructive, so double check you got the input and output files/devices correct
Now, once imaged, the disk won't have the full size of the new disk.
I'll run parted to resize the disk - since in this case I just imaged to sdb - there might be other, better tools for this.
geek@zephyr:~$ sudo parted /dev/sdb
GNU Parted 3.6
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Error: The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
OK/Cancel? ok
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sdb appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an
extra 1453406976 blocks) or continue with the current setting?
Fix/Ignore? Fix

Pick Fix
This should reflect the same layout as your original drive
Model: JMicron Tech (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  17.8MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres, no_automount
 2      17.8MB  256GB   256GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata

(parted)

Now to figure out what size we have left

(parted) print free
Model: JMicron Tech (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
        17.4kB  1049kB  1031kB  Free Space
 1      1049kB  17.8MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres, no_automount
 2      17.8MB  256GB   256GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
        256GB   1000GB  744GB   Free Space

(parted)

And to resize to it
 resizepart 2 1000GB

Replacing 1000GB to whatever your end of free space was. Print one more time to confirm the space is filled
(parted) print
Model: JMicron Tech (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  17.8MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres, no_automount
 2      17.8MB  1000GB  1000GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata

At this point (and I don't have a way to test this for reasons), you should be able to install your drive back to the laptop and boot it.

I think instead of sudo parted /dev/sdb, you might be better off with sudo sgdisk -e /dev/sdb. This would move the backup GPT data structures to the end of the disk. Once you have booted Windows, you could use Microsoft's Disk Management to add the free space to the NTFS volume.

possibly. I also feel like clonezilla was a lot less painful than this :D

It may have been painful to figure it out or piece together from knowledge you already had.  From my perspective this is fantastic though.  I can do all the work on an English keyboard and big screens I can read easily and don't have to buy an additional USB memory stick or even reboot anything (except obviously the patient, after installing its new brain).  Worst case scenario is that it doesn't work and I go the USB-boot-media-with-clonezilla path.  Fantastic answer and many thanks, I'll mark it as correct after verifying.

The resizing is the bit I'm the most iffy about. I'm debating a windows answer, but can't think of free imaging software I trust enough.
